# Taking Values from a Excel Sheet and using them as Tags in Azure

Tags: excel, azure, powershell, scripting, power-automate

so I have a Excel Sheet with Information for some Servers which are on the Azure Cloud. And I wanna take some of the Information and use these as Tags for some on the servers. I could just do it one by one but that would take a lot of time.. so what I wanna do is a PowerShell script (MS Flow is also available).
So this would be what I wanna do for example:

1.Lets say I got this kind of sheet(in the pic) and I got the servers in column A with the same name in Azure

2.What I want to do then is put the yellow marked information into Azure as tags but it obviously has to be the correct server.

I think I will to make some kind of a loop right? Would be very nice if anyone could help me.. as I am pretty new to PowerShell & Azure.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OnMx.png this is the picture

Answer (score 0):

Check this site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest

You should check if the resource exists (using the show for example, and store it in a variable)

```
az resource show -g MyResourceGroup -n MyVm --resource-type "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
```

And add the tag

```
az resource tag --tags vmlist=vm1 -g MyResourceGroup -n MyVm --resource-type "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
```